# Javascript Objects and keys

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

The following command shows the properties of an Object.

```
var keys = Object.keys(result);
```

Output: [requester.client.id,request.id]

When I try to print an alert(result[request.id]) or alert(result.request.id) I dont get the values. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: have you tried alert(result['request.id']);

Comment: @NickAvi what? "request.id" as string?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes; as far as I can tell, the OP here appears to have properties named `requester.client.id` and `request.id` (i.e., the property names have period characters in them).

Comment: Instead of `alert`, try your browser's developer console. You can inspect objects, set breakpoints and perform other useful debugging operations.

Comment: @apsillers Yes, I got it now after a second look, anyway... seems to me that something is wrong down there...

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick. result['request.id']) works like charm :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript objects keys are strings, though they can have periods. What you probably getting as the output is `['requester.client.id','request.id']`, so it should be accessed as `result['requester.client.id']`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `result` object has properties named `"requester.client.id"` and `"request.id"`.

You need to do `alert(result["request.id"])`.

`result[request.id]` does not work because `request` here is treated as a variable name, and you probably have no variable named `request`.

`result.request.id` is closer, but it also fails because the property name has a period in it, so the parser treats this as the the `id` property of the `request` property of `result`.